# Easier way to create a custom Laravel Blade directive when a string is being concatenated with variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, directive

I created the following blade directive:

```
    Blade::directive('bundle', function ($component) {
        $string = "\":langs='\" . file_get_contents(base_path() . \"/resources/bundles/\" . App::currentLocale() . \"/$component.json\").\"'\";";
        return ("<?php echo " . $string . "?>");
    });
```

To better understand what's going on, this is the code that I would like to represent with that string above (but being a Blade directive this is not an option):

```php
$path = base_path() . "\\resources\\bundles\\" . App::currentLocale() ."\\$component.json";
$json = file_get_contents($path);
return "<?php echo \":langs='\" $json \"'\"; ?>
```

As it is now, the Blade directive above won't work when there are single quotes within the .json file due to the external quotation marks being the single ones too. But in any case, it feels like it's too hard to wrap my head around creating this string, I was wondering, is there an easier way to generate that final string to echo out the result?

Comment: I dont get it. Your directive contains `:langs`, while the generated code doesn't. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Sorry, since it didn't work earlier I was reconstructing that part again over here, I corrected that. To clear things up, what I want to do is to pass a prop to a Vue component containing a Json with translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a helper function and return a string calling that one function from the blade directive:

```
Blade::directive('bundle', function ($bundle) {
    return ":langs=\"{{json_bundle_translations($bundle)}}\"";          
});
```

And then the helper function looks like:

```
    function json_bundle_translations($bundle)
{
    $path = base_path() . "\\resources\\bundles\\" . App::currentLocale() . "\\$bundle.json";
    return file_get_contents($path);
}
```

It feels easier to understand rather than having strings within strings inside the directive and it's also giving a function to retrieve the Json alone in case it's needed.

I'll leave this question open for a while to see if someone can come up with a better solution.

Edit: The best way I found to create complex blade directives without having to deal with a lengthy string was just to call a helper method

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get the correct quote escaping with that.

Comment: With this solution I can leverage the power of the blade templating engine to get the correct escaping of characters, it does a pretty good job at it. I tested the Json I was having trouble with before and seems to be working, but let me know if you come up with a case where this may fail

Comment: The difference is, you'll get a string as a props instead of object if you're using your implementation. You'll get an object using my implementation. Not a big deal if you just need a directive that works.

Comment: I wanted a string in here since it would get decoded anyway to be sent to the component. I am looking to get the best solution in here, do you see any disadvantages to this approach? The only argument I had against so far is that understanding the code with a helper function within a string is slightly harder than having it all there. The arguments for it are that the function is getting documented anyway and can be renamed to make it clear that it's a helper function. Also, having a separate class that is actually PHP and not a string helps with its maintainability too.

Comment: No argument. Use what it suits you. For me, it's better props passed as an object. Having good maintainability in the Vue side.

Comment: And like what I've said above, you can extract my implementation a little bit more (e.g. move the json_encode bla bla bla to the helper function) actually, if you need more `maintainability`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, this is what I've got:

```php
Blade::directive('bundle', function ($component) {
    $encoding = JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT;
    $component = trim($component, "'\" ");

    $string = sprintf(
        '":langs=\'" . json_encode(json_decode(file_get_contents(%s), true), %d) . "\'"',
        'resource_path("bundles/" . App::getLocale() . "/' . $component . '.json")',
        $encoding
    );

    return ('<?php echo ' . $string . '?>');
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the `App::currentLocale()` result is getting cached on the Laravel view, when the language is changed the view is not getting updated. For now I wrote a helper function and I am just returning a call to that function from the directive. Seems to be also a bit easier to read than having a lot of string within strings.

Comment: I see, then just move the getLocale (I think there is no `currentLocale`, it's should be `getLocale`) as a string. I've update my answer. I think it's still readable. It's easier to extract a little bit more using another sprintf if you need more readable..